Migrating to Kotlin 2.0.0 causes compile time errors associated with nullablity
I am currently migrating my Android application to Kotlin 2.0.0:
val myConfig: Configuration? = null
val myFrameRate: String? =
    getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("my_FrameRate", "0")

myConfig?.myFrameRate = myFrameRate!!.toInt()
myConfig?.myFrameRate = myFrameRate.toInt()

With this data class:
data class Configuration(
    var myFrameRate: Int,
)

For Kotlin version 1.9.+ the above compiles and runs fine, but with Kotlin 2.0.0 the last line now fails my build with a compile error:

Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type 'kotlin.String?'.

However I then get this warning in Android Studio:
Unnecessary non-null assertion (!!) on a non-null receiver of type String

Is there something I am missing when migrating to Kotlin 2.0.0?

Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre]. It is especially important to know how myFramerate is declared, what its visibility is and how it can be otherwise accessed.

This is not a reproducible example. Please [edit] again and provide a [mre] that we can actually execute.

Although it is reproducible now, it is still far from minimal. I took the liberty and edited the question to remove everything that wasn't necessary to reproduce the problem. Please verify that this is still what you wanted to ask.

Kotlin 2.0.0 is correct, 1.9.x shouldn't have allowed that either.
To find out why that is a problem just replace getPreferences(...).getString(...) with null and change your last line to this:
 println(myFrameRate.toInt())

Kotlin 1.9.x will compile your app just fine, but when you run it it will crash with a runtime exception on the last line:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null

Kotlin 2.0.0 prevents you from compiling this code in the first place.
The issue here is that you use a nullsafe call (?.) on the left side of an assignment. If the left results in null, the evaluation of the right side is skipped altogether (see last paragraph here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls).
In your example, the first time you access myFrameRate, when the left side is null, your not-null assertion (!!) is skipped. Therefore on the line below it is wrong for the compiler to assume that that assertion has actually taken place and myFrameRate can now be safely accessed.
The compiler cannot tell that getString will never return null, because that is a Java function that does not provide any information about nullability. But you, as the programmer, know that. So it is fine to use !!, but just apply it to getString directly:
val myFrameRate: String =
    getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("my_FrameRate", "0")!!

The rest of your code will work now without further !! in both Kotlin versions.

There is just one issue left: You observed an inconsistency of error messages / warnings.
For one, the compile error with Kotlin 2.0.0 only occurred when you actually tried to build your app, Android Studio didn't show you this up front. And your first attempt to fix the error resulted in the false positive warning "Unnecessary non-null assertion (!!) on a non-null receiver of type String".
The reason for that is that Kotlin 2.0.0 introduced a new compiler, the K2 compiler. But the built-in compiler of Android Studio that is used for syntax highlighting, code completion, compile warnings and so on still uses the old compiler. Hence, any improvements the new K2 compiler brings (like the enhanced null-safety discussed above) are only visible when actually building the app.
This is just temporary because Kotlin 2.0.0 is still very new. There already is experimental support for K2 in Android Studio, but you will have to wait for one of the next AS releases to fully support it.
If you want to enable the experimental K2 support in Android Studio right now, follow the instructions in the release notes of Kotlin 2.0.0: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew20.html#support-in-ides
